# Java. Не получается скрыть панель

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Не получается скрыть JPanel по нажатию на кнопку. Выдает ошибку на строку `Menu.setVisible(false);`. Что нужно исправить? (Окно выводится с помощью другого класса)

Так же,если есть какие-либо советы по улучшению кода,буду рад выслушать.

```
package p1;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Window extends JFrame {
    int vert,hor,ma,mb;

    Window(){
        super("p1");
        Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        vert = sSize.height;
        hor  = sSize.width;

        ma=300;
        mb=30;

        setResizable(false);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel Menu = new JPanel();
        JButton Back = new JButton("Назад");
        JButton Settings = new JButton("Настройки");
        JButton Exit = new JButton("Выход");

        Menu.setLayout(null);
        Menu.setBackground(Color.red);

        Settings.setSize(ma, mb);
        Settings.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),200);
        Settings.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SettingsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        Menu.add(Settings);

    private void SettingsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Menu.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что за ошибка то?

Comment: На setVisible ругается почему-то

Comment: Судя по коду ругаться должно на то, что он(компилятор) не знает такой переменной. Если это так, то вам надо почитать про области видимости переменных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте закрытие `Menu` добавить внутрь `ActionListener`:

```
Settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        SettingsActionPerformed(evt);
    }

    private void SettingsActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Menu.setVisible(false);
    }
});
Menu.add(Settings);
```